# how to use stopword sastrawi library python if data from file excel or csv

Tags: python, arrays, excel, stop-words

I can't use the data from file excel for implement in function stopwords

I have tried like this

The data can show with column hadist

```
train['hadis'] = train['hadis'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.stopword.remove() for x in x.split()))
train['hadis'].head()
```

but error result

```
from Sastrawi.StopWordRemover.StopWordRemoverFactory import     
StopWordRemoverFactory
factory = StopWordRemoverFactory()
stopword = factory.create_stop_word_remover()

kalimat = 'Dengan Menggunakan Python dan Library Sastrawi saya dapat 
melakukan proses Stopword Removal'
stop = stopword.remove(kalimat)
print(stop)
```

result output is a success to missing `saya` & `dan`

but my question is how if the variable value `kalimat` is from data excel with so many row data?

Comment: You should use a loop to read every row in the file to process.

Comment: could you give an example @Yusufsn

Comment: Put your sample data (including the columns) from your excel file in your question. Or simple, if your file is `csv`, you can use `pandas.read_csv('filename')`. Then read every row in specific column.

Comment: I did it @Yusufsn, please look my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make an assumption that your excel file is in `csv` format named `kalimat.csv`, and `kalimat` is the column that contains the sentence you want to analyze.

`kalimat.csv`:

```
no |                                           kalimat
------------------------------------------------------
 1 | saya semua perbuatan tergantung niatnya dan ba...
 2 | terkadang datang kepadaku seperti suara gemeri...
 3 | bacalah beliau menjawab aku tidak bisa baca na...
 4 | Dengan Menggunakan Python dan Library Sastrawi...
```

Try this code:

```
from Sastrawi.StopWordRemover.StopWordRemoverFactory import StopWordRemoverFactory
import pandas as pd

factory = StopWordRemoverFactory()
stopword = factory.create_stop_word_remover()

df = pd.read_csv("kalimat.csv")
for i, kalimat in enumerate (df['kalimat']):
    stop = stopword.remove(kalimat)
    print(i,stop + '\n')
```

Output:

```
0 semua perbuatan tergantung niatnya ba... 
1 terkadang datang kepadaku suara gemeri... 
2 bacalah beliau menjawab aku bisa baca na... 
3 Dengan Menggunakan Python Library Sastrawi...
```

Comment: can you help for the result like this in below :

0    saya semua perbuatan tergantung niatnya dan ba...
1    terkadang datang kepadaku seperti suara gemeri...
2    bacalah beliau menjawab aku tidak bisa baca na...
Name: hadis, dtype: object

Comment: Are they the sentences in your excel file?

Comment: yes, they aren't @yusufsn, could you help for the result like on my first comment

Comment: your output written, can you make like data your assume? keep data in each row

Comment: I don't understand what your expected result is. Do you want to save the result in excel file as well? Please provide your expected result in your question. So that I can understand what you are trying to do. If yes, you can make a list of the result, then save into `csv` file using `.to_csv()`

Comment: this is the result from your code https://s.id/4vBOW
this results I hope https://s.id/4vBX-

sorry, n thanks @Yusufsn

Comment: Add `\n` in `print()` section. Write `print (stop + '\n')`. I updated the answer for the 2nd time.

Comment: thanks for your all answer, but just for one question again

Comment: can you change that code for loop to be like this bro     

train['hadis'] = train['hadis'].apply(lambda x: "".join(stopword.remove() for x in x ))
train['hadis'].head()

I need on like that code for save in array data and keep on track, please if you can
@yusufsn

Comment: Just try this: `df['kalimat'] = df['kalimat'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(stopword.remove(x) for x in x.split()))`. Then write `df['kalimat'].head()`

Comment: you are so awesome bro, thank you very much @Yusufsn